# How to run perl script from any where (any directory)

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I have a perl script exist in the follwoing path (/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin/tool.pl)
Every time I want to run this tool I go to the terminal

```
>
```

and then change the directory to

..../bin>

Then I run the perl by writing

```
..../bin> perl tool.pl file= whatever config= whatever
```

The problem is that I want to run this perl script without the need to go to the bin folder where it exist . so I can run perl script from any directory and as soon as I enter shell
I went to the etc/environment and I wrote the follwoing

export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin

But when I go to terminal and write the follwoing straight ahead without going to bin folder where tool.pl exist

```
>perl tool.pl file=... config=...
```

it says the file "tool.pl" does not exist???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument to the `perl` program is the path to an executable file. These calls are equivalent:

```
:~$ perl /home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin/tool.pl
:~$ perl ~/Desktop/Tools/bin/tool.pl
:~$ perl ./Desktop/Tools/bin/tool.pl
:~/Desktop/Tools/bin$ perl tool.pl
:~/Desktop/Tools/bin$ perl ./tool.pl
```

etc.

In the shell the tilde `~` expands to your home directory, and `./` symbolizes the current directory. On *nix shells (including the various terminal emulators on ubuntu), the command prompt ususally is `$` in nomal mode, `#` as root user and seldom `%`. `>` Is a secondary command prompt, e.g. when continuing a multiline argument, unlike cmd.exe on Windows.

The `PERL5LIB` variable determines where Perl looks for modules, not for executable files.

You can set a script as executable via `chmod +x FILENAME`. You can then call the script without specifying the `perl` program:

```
:~/Desktop/Tools/bin$ ./tool.pl
```

You can modify the `PATH` variable to change where the shell looks for executables. The `PATH` usually contains `/usr/bin/` and other directories. You can add a directory of your own via

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin
```

Add your directory at *the end* of the `PATH`es, so you don't overrule other programs.

If you want to set this permanently, you can add this line to the file `~/.bashrc` (only for your user and only for the `bash` shell).

Then you can call your script from anywhere, without a full path name:

```
:~/foo/bar$ tool.pl
```

You should consider using a more specific command name in this case, to prevent name clashes.

Comment: Just One question should I change [chmod +x FILENAME] to be [chmod +x tool.pl] ? and where should I write it ? I will ask another question but in another comment sir!

Comment: I went to environment file and I found the following [ PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games" ] So should I complete the list by writing at the end [:/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin] so the final PATH will be [PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin"] or should I write it as the following [PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games" $ PATH=$PATH:/home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin]. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: `chmod +x FILENAME` is a shell command. So type it into the terminal, or modfiy the permissions in a file manager, e.g. Nautilus. You should be in the directory of the `tool.pl`, but `FILENAME` can be *any* path to a file. If you require info about a command in your shell, you can type `info COMMAND` (or `help COMMAND` in the case of built-ins). `COMMAND --help` often works as well.

Comment: It would probably be best to add a new line at the end of the `~/.bashrc` and write a comment explaining your modification, so you can roll back if needed.

Comment: Sir, I went to the terminal and then to the directory where  bin folder exist and wrote `chmod +x tool.pl` but when I try this `:~/Desktop/Tools/bin$ tool.pl` it says `tool.pl: command not found` It does not recognize that it is an executable file!! please help !

Comment: @Wahedsaw Sorry, to force the shell to only search the current directory and not the path, you have to say `./tool.pl`. Only when you made the addition to the `PATH` you can call the tool as `tool.pl`