# run perl scripts from PATH folder in command prompt

Tags: windows, perl, command-prompt, path-variables

I want to run a perl script located in a PATH directory.
Now command prompt does not search arguments in PATH directories. It just search files in current directory.

```
C:\Users\dg>echo %PATH%
...;C:\Users\dg\abc

C:\Users\dg>dir /a-d /b abc
abc.pl

C:\Users\dg>perl abc.pl
Can't open perl script "abc.pl": No such file or directory
```

Any solution or work around?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436587/how-to-run-perl-script-from-any-where-any-directory) should help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `abc.pl` should work for you if Perl is installed properly. Note, if you use `perl abc.pl`, bash won't search the path for `abc.pl` either: it will look in the current working directory and die if the file doesn't exist

If you want Perl to search the path for the script file then use the `-S` option

```
perl -S abc.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with `cd` to your script directory. Run the folowing:
 `path_to_perl\perl.exe abc.pl`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows.  I have set the .pl extension to be opened by perl, using `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations`.  Then the command `abc.pl` works fine as long as it is on the path, as it is in your example.