# How to run perl script on Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu

How to run perl script on Ubuntu?
How to run this script 
https://zwitterion.org/software/aggregate-cidr-addresses/

I’ve created the file aggregate-cidr-addresses as shown in the example.

I’ve copied the file from the server in the same directory

then I run as shown in the example

```
root@Ubuntu:~$ list-iana-reserved-ranges | aggregate-cidr-addresses
list-iana-reserved-ranges: ukaz ni bil najden (translate command not found)
aggregate-cidr-addresses: ukaz ni bil najden (translate command not found)
```

and also

```
root@Ubuntu:~$ perl list-iana-reserved-ranges | aggregate-cidr-addresses
Number found where operator expected at list-iana-reserved-ranges line 2, near "192.168.1.0"
(Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at list-iana-reserved-ranges line 2, near "192.168.1.0"
Execution of list-iana-reserved-ranges aborted due to compilation errors.
aggregate-cidr-addresses: ukaz ni bil najden (translate command not found)
```

I've got

```
command not found
```

How to run this properly?

Comment: "Nothing worked" isn't real descriptive. What happened? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run perl script from any where (any directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436587/how-to-run-perl-script-from-any-where-any-directory)

Comment: If an executable isn't in a directory in your path, you need to explicitly provide the path to it. `./list-iana-reserved-ranges` etc. That error when you tried running it directly through perl suggests it's not a perl program, btw...

Answer (score 3):

To run a Perl script,

- put the interpreter in the first line of the files with a "shabang" or "hash bang" (`#!`), which the script you linked to already has:

`#!/usr/bin/perl`

- make the files executable:

`chmod +x list-iana-reserved-ranges aggregate-cidr-addresses`

- add `./` to the beginning of the filenames (this is a Linux security feature to not accidentally run scripts in your current directory):

`./list-iana-reserved-ranges | ./aggregate-cidr-addresses`

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env perl` would be even better.

Comment: Thanks. I had wondered about the `env` form of the shebang and today I finally looked it up: [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/). According to the accepted and top answer, it's not _necessarily_ better. It depends.